# Can't read data from kafka with spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-zeppelin

Bear with me I'm new to this. I'm trying to read a kafka stream from a zeppelin note book but it's not returning any data. But when I try to read the topic from the command line it does in fact return data.

```
C:\kafka_2.13-2.6.0>bin\windows\kafka-console-consumer.bat --topic quickstart-events --from-beginning --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 

This is my first event
This is my second event
```

This is my code:

```
val sourceTopic = "quickstart-events" 
val targetTopic = "sensor-processed"
val kafkaBootstrapServer = "127.0.0.1:9092"

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

 val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.appName("Simple Application")
    .config("spark.master", "local").getOrCreate()

val rawData = sparkSession.readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBootstrapServer)
    .option("subscribe", sourceTopic)
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
    .load()

case class SensorData(id: String, ts: Long, value: Double)

import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
val schema = Encoders.product[SensorData].schema

val rawValues = rawData.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").as[String]

val visualizationQuery = rawValues.writeStream
    .queryName("visualization")
    .outputMode("append")
    .format("memory")
    .start()

val sampleDataset = sparkSession.sql("select * from visualization")

sampleDataset.count
```

The count returns 0, when there should be two events.

My dependencies

```
org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.7    
org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.0 
org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.4.7  
org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.4.7
```

Comment: If the data is "This is my first event" it is normal that does not work because that isn´t JSON. Drop the select(from_json(..))

Comment: Thanks for that. But right now I tried using the rawValues dataset on the writeStream method and still got the same results.